# How to reshape (None, 10)-dimensional tensor to (None, None, 10) in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to feed variable-sized sequences into an LSTM. Hence I am using a generator and a batch-size of 1.
I have a `(sequence_length,)`-input-tensor which is embedded, and outputs a `(batch_size, sequence_length, embeding_dimension)`-tensor.
In parallel, the other input data I have is of size `(sequence_length, features)` i.e. `(None, 10)`, which I want to reshape to `(batch_size, sequence_length, features)` i.e. `(None, None, 10)`.

I have tried using the Keras Reshape-Layer with target_shape `(-1, 10)` which should be equivalent to unfolding `(None, 10)` to `(None, None, 10)`, but what I receive is a `(None, 1, 10)` tensor, which makes it impossible to Concatenate this and the embedded Data in order to feed it to an LSTM.
My code:

```py
cluster = Input(shape=(None,))
embeded = Embedding(115, 25, input_length = None)(cluster)

features = Input(shape=(10,)) #variable
reshape = Reshape(target_shape=(-1, 10))(features)

merged = Concatenate(axis=-1)([embeded, reshape])

[...]

model.fit_generator(generator(), steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=5)
```

Output:

```
[...]
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, None, 25), (None, 1, 10)]
```

How can I reshape a `(None, 10)` to a `(None, None, 10)` tensor in Keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this Keras won't have any benefit over doing reshaping in NumPy. You can:

```
# perform reshaping prior to passing to Keras
features = Input(shape=(None, 10))
```

and perform the reshaping prior to passing to Keras where you have the actual `batch_size` and `sequence_length` available in your input.